# SQL Connection failing

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, datagridview

I am trying to execute the following code (certain bits have been edited for security)

```
private void ServiceMainScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DataTable stuff = new DataTable();
        //stuff.Select("select "WorkOrder"."WorkOrderID", "Customer"."FirstName", "Vehicles"."Model", "WorkOrder"."State" from "WorkOrder", "Customer", "Vehicles" WHERE "WorkOrder"."VIN" = "Vehicles"."VIN" AND "Vehicles"."CustomerID" = "Customer"."CustomerID" AND "WorkOrder"."State" = 'In Progress';
        try
        {
            string commands = "select \"WorkOrder\".\"WorkOrderID\", \"Customer\".\"FirstName\", \"Vehicles\".\"Model\", \"WorkOrder\".\"State\"  from \"WorkOrder\", \"Customer\", \"Vehicles\" WHERE \"WorkOrder\".\"VIN\" = \"Vehicles\".\"VIN\" AND \"Vehicles\".\"CustomerID\" = \"Customer\".\"CustomerID\" AND \"WorkOrder\".\"State\" = 'In Progress'";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=rowkir0911;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commands, conn))
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    dgvDisplayWOs.DataSource = table;
                    dgvDisplayWOs.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be able to find the database. I am access to the Get Started/Application Express of the database as well as the SQL command line, but I need the program to generate a table. I am using Winforms with C# on Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You must open SQL connection by calling `conn.Open();` before executing any command.

Comment: I added conn.Open(); and it's still not working. I updated my code sample.

Comment: @user3169698, Any exception?

Comment: It says that it cannot find the database or it is not accessible. I can connect to it just fine if I use Add New DataSource, but I need to display the results of an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your connection string or query specifies the database name.
You can either modify your connection string

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=rowkir0911;Persist Security Info=True;initial catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"))
```

Or you can modify the query to use qualified table name like [DB].[Schema].[Table]

Comment: What goes into the initial catalog?

Comment: The name of database. You can also check [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to connect to Oracle. But you are using classes from System.Data.SqlClient which is for connecting to SQL Server database.

Use ODP.Net instead. You can find all the necessary classes under Oracle.DataAccess.Client

**Update**

You need to add a reference to the Oracle.DataAccess.dll assembly.

Here is a code you can try -

```
   using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
   .
   .
   .
   try
    {
        string commands = "select \"WorkOrder\".\"WorkOrderID\", \"Customer\".\"FirstName\", \"Vehicles\".\"Model\", \"WorkOrder\".\"State\"  from \"WorkOrder\", \"Customer\", \"Vehicles\" WHERE \"WorkOrder\".\"VIN\" = \"Vehicles\".\"VIN\" AND \"Vehicles\".\"CustomerID\" = \"Customer\".\"CustomerID\" AND \"WorkOrder\".\"State\" = 'In Progress'";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=rowkir0911;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"))
        using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(commands, conn))
        {
            command.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
                dgvDisplayWOs.DataSource = table;
                dgvDisplayWOs.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```